# How to enable Jquery calender of specfic range using PHP and Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have tried on stack overflow and lots more other sites and get solutions of that.
Here is PHP Code

```
$fromDate = $results_min_max->min_date; // month / day / year
$toDate = $results_min_max->max_date;  // month / day / year

$dateMonthYearArr = array();
$fromDateSTR = strtotime($fromDate);
$toDateSTR = strtotime($toDate);

for ($currentDateSTR = $fromDateSTR; $currentDateSTR <= $toDateSTR; $currentDateSTR += (60 * 60 * 24)) {
    // use date() and $currentDateSTR to format the dates in between
    $currentDateStr = date("j-n-Y",$currentDateSTR);
    $dateMonthYearArr[] = $currentDateStr;
    //print $currentDateStr."<br />";
}
```

Hope this may help someone.

Comment: first describe the problem, than answer separately if you want to share the knowledge.

Comment: And where is your jquery?